# How can I show notes on my laptop in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: multiple-monitors, libreoffice, presentation

I think it would be very nice to present on a projector with my laptop showing the notes! I appreciate any help and I love you if you find it by tomorrow!

Comment: Do you mean notes?
The presentation on the beamer is usually fullscreen so..do you want the notes to show at the bottom of your slides? If yes you can copy them over..but I guess you want a magical link from your existing notes on your presentation slides?

Comment: Hi, i want to see the notes on one, the presantation on the other screen (beamer).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work more or less out of the box:

1. Make sure you have the presenter console extension installed:
   `apt-get install libreoffice-presenter-console`
2. plug your external display or beamer to the laptop
3. unset the display mirroring in the Ubuntu display settings
4. in Impress, go to `Slide Show/Slide Show Settings` and choose the correct presentation display from the list.
5. start the presentation (e.g. hit <kbd>F5</kbd>)

You should now see a different screen on your laptop and the external display or beamer. The laptop version should also show any slide notes you have (click on the notes button at the bottom).

[image: laptop view of the presentation using the presenter console extension]

**Notes**:

- This is also valid for OpenOffice.org. In that case the package to install is `openoffice.org-presenter-console`.

Comment: The Notes are shown, but the slides dont switch together with the presentation. i would have to switch the slides on both the presentation and the notes... Not good enough in a presentation situation.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot the most important part: the presenter console. I updated the answer.

Comment: 10 mins before the presentation of my results xD =)=)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm happy it worked and I could help :)