# Showing slide show in the projector

Tags: libreoffice, slideshow, projector

I successfully plugged in the projector in to my Acer 8930G computer, but when I'm tryng to show the slide show (like in Image Viewer or LibreOffice Impress), it begins in my laptop, though I'd like to start it in the projector screen. How can I show a slide show on the external display?

At my school, where Windows and MS Office are used, there's also problems like this.

Comment: Follow the answer here and you should be all set: http://askubuntu.com/questions/198492/how-can-i-show-notes-on-my-laptop-in-libreoffice-impress/198520#198520

Answer (score 1):

I usually set my displays to mirror mode. Start `displays` from Unity, it should show you both displays, and click on the "mirror displays":

[image]

Comment: I tried that too, but it was not able to enable.